# How long did it take you to learn Objective-C probably?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, programming-languages

I have a question I really want answered. I have been playing around with some Objective-C for a few weeks, and I have been reading in the book [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503619) until Chapter 7.

In chapter 5 and 6, there is a challenge you should do, especially chapter 5 where he write:

> This exercise is an important challenge that you should do before moving on. Although it is easy to follow my instructions, you will eventually want to create your own applications. Here is where you can start to develop some independence.

But I have not been successful on those challenges: tbh, I have no idea how to do them...
It does not even help to look back the previous chapters and steal the code, I have no idea how to make it work and what I should be typing.

So my question is: how long did it take you to probably know Objective-C? For those who have read the book: where you able to do the challenges?

I really want to learn Objective-C program for the iPhone, but now that I don't even know how to do the challenges, I doubt it's possible for me to learn it... Is there still hope?

It should also be said that besides the challenges, much of the code he writes makes no sense to me. I am not sure why he writes it and what it does 100%. Please help me on this one!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean 'properly', or are you wanting people to say 'well, after four weeks I guess I may have learned it, but I don't know'?

Comment: Guess it's properly then. My native language is Danish, so sorry for typos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds to me like all you need is a conceptual foundation.

Like you, I came from C, so I've been there.

Start here:

- [Object-Oriented Programming with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/)

Then, learn Objective-C (the actual language) and Cocoa or Cocoa Touch:

- [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/)
- [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/) (covers both Cocoa and Cocoa Touch, as the concepts are largely the same)
- [Memory Management Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/) (and Cocoa Touch)
- [Model Object Implementation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/)
- [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/) (Cocoa Touch specific)

Don't worry about how long it'll take. Take your time. Work as fast or as slowly as you want.

> I really want to learn Objective-C program for the iPhone, but now that I don't even know how to do the challenges, I doubt it's possible for me to learn it... Is there still hope?
>
> It should also be said that besides the challenges, much of the code he writes makes no sense to me. I am not sure why he writes it and what it does 100%.

If you're trying to implement them on the iPhone, that may be the problem: The book is *Cocoa* Programming *for Mac OS X*, and Cocoa and Cocoa Touch have some big differences between their application frameworks (AppKit in Cocoa, UIKit in Cocoa Touch). I would say either learn Cocoa (and implement the examples as Mac apps) first, since that's the book you have, or abandon that book and switch to one more iPhone-appropriate.

The Hillegass book gets a lot of recommendations, so if you find a different one that's better for iOS programmers who want to skip the Mac, don't be afraid to recommend it.

ETA: Also, if you don't want to program the Mac at all, your local library would probably love a current copy of the Hillegass book.

Comment: This is really good! I will defiantly take a look on all the links when I got time. For the quote and your respond: I am not trying to implement the examples on an iPhone. What I meant was that my target for programming was the iPhone. Now you mention AppKit and UIKit, will it be a waste of my time to read that book if I want to focus on iPhone? Is the difference big enough when I am still in the learning phase? Again, thanks for the links, will look them through.

Comment: ninjaboi21: I haven't read much of the Hillegass book, but from what I have, yes: It teaches you how to write Mac applications, not iPhone applications. There are concepts in common (such as responders, target-action, and delegates), but the iOS world isn't starved for its own books anymore. So, if you only want to program the iPhone, I suggest you find a Cocoa-Touch-specific book. Alternatively, just use the Apple docs—that's what I did when learning to program the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a few days... had to do a couple of iphone apps, and as such picked it up.

My advice (although I'm liable to get shouted at) is to forget the examples in the books. Just apply yourself. Set yourself a challenge, and find out what you need to achieve it. You will learn by doing. :p Even though books may help, its essentially doing it that gets you the experience.

Once you know what an "object" is and how it works in objective c then you are pretty much set. All you need to find out is what objects to use. Everything else is pretty straightforward after that (trying not to say "easy" lol, but its straightforward).

Comment: I have an iPhone app in mind that should not be too complex. That's my goal for now. The problem is: I have no idea where to start but the GUI. The 'just jump into it. Do some few examples, download some samples and figure them out' doesn't really work for me. I hope you follow along what I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to iTunes and search for CS193P, you will find the video and slides from the [CS193P class at stanford](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/iphone-application-programming-spring-2009/id384233222). Did I mention they are free?!

Answer (score 1):

I learnt the basics of objective c from newboston.com . He is a good tutor.. here is the link for it...  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Xqn5IHbusA

Answer (score 1):

I literally *just* got started and I found [an awesome tutorial online](http://cupsofcocoa.com/2010/08/29/learn-objective-c-in-24-days/) that has taught me some basics. I'm about 30% through it. Only been two days so far and learned a lot. It's fairly short, but descriptive (not as tedious as other tutorials)

Today, I bought another book that seems good for simple iPhone apps. It's called iOS SDK Programming: A Beginner's Guide. Looks good because it shows a good connection between the Objective-C language and Xcode's Interface Builder (the really appealing visual stuff :] )

Answer (score 0):

Can you already program?
I'd always suggest starting with a scripting language (Ruby and Python are very easy to learn) and not moving onto a harder language, like Objective-C, until you are 100% comfortable with the basics.

Comment: I only know the basics in C (a procedural language).
Like if, else-if, do, while, for loops. Haven't touched pointers in C tho.

Comment: I'd definitely advise you to learn some OOP in Ruby (or something similar) before attempting it in Objective-C. That's just me, though.

Comment: Can you offer me any good place to start learning Ruby or Python? Sounds likes that what I need to get started.

Comment: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/ - Ruby in Twenty Minutes is a nice start

Answer (score 0):

I say don't lose hope!

I *highly* suggest having a foundation in [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) before diving into Objective-C as Cocoa Touch (the foundation of iOS) is very dependent on that programming paradigm.

I used [iPhone Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://amzn.to/96vELB) to learn Objective-C from an iOS-specific perspective. It took me about 2-3 weeks between work and school to complete the book and ready to tackle my own projects. Like the book you described, the Big Nerd Ranch Guide has some additional challenges that you can do to test your knowledge and ability to reference Apple's documentation.

If you haven't already done so, bookmark [Apple's own documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/) as it's the best reference material you will find.

Comment: That books looks awesome! I like Aaron Hillegass, thinks he got a great way of teaching, and his use of word is fine for a Dane :) For the documentation, is it possible you can link all of Apple's reference? Tried their developer site, but I am not sure if it was the right documentation I found. Is this the right one, [Mac Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation)? Thanks!